# How do you register a namespace with Silex autoloader

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm experimenting with creating an extension with the [Silex php micro framework](http://silex-project.org) for user authentication but I can't seem to get the autoloader to work. Can anyone shed any light?

I have a directory structure like this (truncated)

```
usertest
|_lib
| |_silex.phar
| |_MyNamespace
|   |_UserExtension.php
|   |_User.php
|_www
  |_index.php
```

The pertinent bits of index.php, which serves as the bootstrap and the front controller look like this:

```
require '../lib/silex.phar';

use Silex\Application;
use MyNamespace\UserExtension;

$app = new Application();
$app['autoloader']->registerNamespace( 'MyNamespace', '../lib' );
$app->register( new UserExtension() );
```

The class I'm trying to load looks similar this:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ExtensionInterface;

class UserExtension implements ExtensionInterface {
    public function register( Application $app ) {
        $app['user'] = $app->share( function() use( $app ) {
            return new User();
        });
    }
}
```

All pretty straight forward except it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyNamespace\UserExtension' not found in /home/meouw/Projects/php/usertest/www/index.php on line 8
```

I have dabbled with symfony2 and have successfully followed the [instructions for setting up the universal class loader](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/tools/autoloader.html), but in this instance I am stumped. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could not reproduce. I tried it with exactly the code you provided and it succeeded. You're going to have to check your names or share your actual code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd use

```
$app['autoloader']->registerNamespace('MyNamespace', __DIR__.'/../lib');
```

Comment: The autoloader is deprecated in recent versions of Silex, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11339189/187018) for an update.

Comment: @ChrisR your answer is also deprecated now check my answer for the newsest solution

Answer (score 59):

In recent versions of Silex the autoloader is deprecated and you should register all your namespaces through the `composer.json` file which imo is a nicer solution because you are centralizing your autoloading definitions.

Example:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.0.*@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyNameSpace": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

In fact when you try to access the autoloader in any recent version of Silex the following RuntimeException is thrown:

> You tried to access the autoloader service. The autoloader has been removed from Silex. It is recommended that you use Composer to manage your dependencies and handle your autoloading. See http://getcomposer.org for more information.

Comment: As far as I understand, it requires that Composer will be installed on my workstation?

Comment: You can install composer locally in your PHP project, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally

Comment: I can't install it, it needs admin rights. Does pdsr-4 can avoid running composer?

Comment: If you can't install it because you can't run php cli or curl you can just download the PHAR file from https://getcomposer.org/download/ and place it in your project with your filesystem explorer

Answer (score 11):

```
Deprecated - As of 2014-10-21 PSR-0 has been marked as deprecated.
PSR-4 is now recommended as an alternative
```

That is why you should use PSR-4 syntax in composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
      "silex/silex": "1.0.*@dev",
  },
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "Vendor\\Namespace\\": "/path"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me =( `Class "Controllers\MyController" does not exist.`

Comment: You need to have proper directory structure :) and of course change "\Vendor\\namespace": and "/path"

Comment: Worked like a charm! And +1 on PSR-4 vs PSR-0.

Answer (score 3):

To register namespaces, just call `registerNamespaces()` like this:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app['autoloader']->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/',
    'Panda'            => __DIR__.'/../vendor/SilexDiscountServiceProvider/src',
    'Knp'              => __DIR__.'/../vendor/KnpSilexExtensions/',
    // ...
));
```

Answer (score 3):

Both adding appropriate statement to the `autoload` section of `composer.json` and registering namespaces directly calling `registerNamespace` was not working for me, until I executed **`composer update`** in the projects folder.

Comment: it is because composer install needs composer.lock file